# How to allow just local connections for a specific application?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I know I can set tomcat to accept just local connections by editing its configuration files and setting an address there. However, this setting will be applied to every web application I decide to run on it.

I'd like for just a specific web application to accept connections by localhost, maybe returning a default html page in case of a remote connection.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could write a servlet filer and map the resources you need to protect, here is some code you will need:

```
        String host = request.getRemoteHost();
        String address = request.getRemoteAddr();

        if ("localhost".equals(host) || "127.0.0.1".equals(address)) {
      //Accept connecction
           }else{
           //reject connection
            }
```

Make sure the configuration of a reverse proxy in from of tomcat does not mark all the connection as locals! A DNS spoofing brakes it, but it is very unlikely to corrupt your host file!